# Extracting pixel values from dispersed pixels across various countries

Tags: google-earth-engine, zonal-statistics, extract-by-mask, feature-extraction, geemap

I am trying to calculate extreme events of rainfall using ERA-5 Daily Data in Google Earth Engine through Python. I am trying to find pixels that had more rain than the 95th percentile of the previous 20 years on a certain period. You can find the code below:

```py
import ee
import geemap
ee.Initialize()

# Get country information:
countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB/2017")
# Get total precipitation from January 1, 1979 to December 31, 1998
theData = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY').select('total_precipitation').filterDate('1979-01-01', '1999-01-01')
# Use Reducer to calculate 95th Percentile
theDataPerc = theData.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([95]))

# The following (one band) image should have 95 percentile in each pixel
Rain95 = theDataPerc.select('total_precipitation_p95')
# Get the rain for January 1, 1999
todayRain = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY').filterDate('1999-01-01', '1999-01-02').select('total_precipitation').first()

# Subtract 95 percentile from todayRain.
dif95 = todayRain.subtract(Rain95)
# If the difference is positive, then we have an extreme event in that pixel. If the difference is negative, then we do not have an extreme event.
Masking95 = dif95.gt(0)
# Get the observed rain that is above 95 percentile:
masked95 = Masking95.multiply(myRain)

# The next image should have only the pixels that extreme events occured. The other pixels should be null (to the best of my knowledge)
onlyExtremes = masked95.updateMask(masked95.gt(0))
# I want to get a list of pixels where "onlyExtremes" is not null.
```

[image: Dispersed Points Where Extreme Events Occured]

You can see in the image that extreme events are dispersed among different places of the world. Furthermore, I need to do this for too many days. As a result, drawing a square to define a region is not an option as is suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307350/how-i-get-the-masking-area-data-and-export-data-in-google-earth-engine?newreg=bf7fccf9bafb40fab330b60fdf0b655d).

Any command that requires region as an input (for example, ee_to_numpy or ee_export_image) complains about too many edges or too many bytes when I use "countries" as region. As I pointed out previously, I cannot draw rectangles on the places that I observe an extreme event, because I need to do this for many days. Hence, I need to be able to do this in the code without interfering.

Comment: To me it's not clear what you need to do and can't. Your code works fine, so, what is your expected result?

Comment: I am trying to understand in which countries these extreme events were observed and the percentage of the zones in which an extreme event occurred within countries.

Comment: ok, one approach could be creating a binary mask (1:event, 0:no event) and vectorize, then filter a countries table using it... just thinking aloud.. it depends on your needs.

Comment: In my code Masking95 is 1 on the pixels where an extreme even occurred and 0 where it did not. The problem is that, when I directly try to do  "geemap.zonal_statistics(Masking95, countries, 'something.csv', 'MEAN', 10000)" (which should give the percentage of pixels) it says "User memory limit exceeded." I think the reason is google earth engine gets worried about the "20 year" data that I am using. However, I create a single image with that 20 year data. As a result, I am trying to first get the images or pixels where the extreme events occurred, which is not that many actually.

Comment: yeah, but the image you created is not "stored", it computes it on the fly, so needs a big capacity, you're exceeding it. Maybe you could first export your results to an asset, then computing statistics or vectorizing..

Comment: That's what I was trying to ask. How can I do that?